# Styling a ContentControl

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a custom WPF control. It has a nested ContentControl which is bound to the template's Content property, so it can have any object set as its content.

IF the content is a raw string, I want to apply the following style to the TextBlock (I know that when the Visual Tree is actually rendered a ContentPresenter with a TextBlock is generated if you set a ContentControl's Content property to a string).

```
<Style x:Key="Label" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                    <Color A="255" R="82" G="105" B="146" />
                </SolidColorBrush.Color>
            </SolidColorBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I would have thought the way to do this was via nested resources (this is part of my custom control):

```
<ContentControl x:Name="SomeText" Margin="10,10,10,0"
                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                IsTabStop="False" Grid.Column="1">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource Label}" />
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

So...the above says (to me) if the ContentControl ends up with a nested TextBlock, we should apply the Label style, right?...but no, the Label style is not applied in the example above.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using Snoop or StyleSnooper to see what is actually applied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

For an explanation of why the Style for the created `TextBlock` isn't getting applied, see answer 5 at this link: [Textblock style override label style in WPF](http://www.go4answers.com/Example/textbloxk-style-override-label-style-73551.aspx)

> This is because ContentPresenter creates a TextBlock for a string
>   content, and since that TextBlock isn't in the visual tree, it will
>   lookup to Appliacton level resource. And if you difine a style  for
>   TextBlock at Appliaction level, then it will be  applied to these
>   TextBlock within ControlControls.

You could use a `DataTemplateSelector`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="stringTemplate">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource Label}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<local:TypeTemplateSelector x:Key="TypeTemplateSelector"
                            StringTemplate="{StaticResource stringTemplate}" />

<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TypeTemplateSelector}"
                ...>
```

*TypeTemplateSelector example*

```
public class TypeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate StringTemplate { get; set; }

    public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is string)
        {
            return StringTemplate;
        }
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

You'll also have to Bind the Text property for the `TextBlock`

```
<Style x:Key="Label" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding}"/>
    <!-- Additional setters.. -->
</Style>
```

Comment: That's a lot of work...shouldn't I be able to do this more simply?

Comment: @JeffN825: I agree, updated my answer with another approach using a DataTemplateSelector

Comment: Microsoft have a lot to answer for on this. Because of this, even TextBlock.Fontsize doesn't work. I refuse to believe the performance gain of not having the textblock in the visual tree is worth this.

Comment: You can also set the text binding in the template: `<TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource Label}" Text="{Binding}" />`